# How can I create a menu at the bottom on in Android 4.0 upper

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-xml, android-menu

I wanted to create a menu at the bottom of my apps similar to this

[image].

But I looked up Android's developer guide and found ActionBar in Google typically resides at the top of the view. So How can I customize it to my purpose, and come up with an XML layout with menu at the bottom. A sketch of xml would be greatly appreciated 'cause I am really at loss.

Thanks

Comment: Split the action bar. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a split action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar).

For the native API Level 11 action bar, and for ActionBarSherlock, use `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in your manifest for the `<activity>` or `<application>` that you want to have use the split action bar. For the AppCompat action bar, add `<meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                   android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />` to the `<activity>`.

Comment: The primary intention of me asking this question is how to embed a menu in the bottom part view of an activity? Can you show me the xml sketch without using sth like actionbarsherlock. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: @Daniel: If you want your "menu" to look like the screenshot, use the split action bar. You do not need to use ActionBarSherlock to have a split action bar, but you *do* need an action bar from somewhere (e.g., the one built into Android, added at API Level 11). If you do not want your "menu" to look like the screenshot, then please ask a separate SO question where you explain what you want it to look like, what you tried, and what problems you encountered.

Comment: Sorry @CommonsWare, kinda misunderstood split action bar before, it achieved the effect indeed. It's similiar to what I want, but not exactly, I had intended to ask the way to make menu at the bottom of a view.  Sorry I didn't make the question clear, I will start a new thread